# Expression Blend Designer COMException

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, expression-blend

When I open the designer for a specific project in Expression Blend, I get the following error, since checking the box 'Override scaling'.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

This app can't start because the screen resolution is below 1024x768. 
Choose a higher screen resolution and then try again. (Exception from 
HRESULT: 0x80270250)
```

I have tried:

- Restart Blend/PC
- Open designer in another project (this WORKS, leading me to believe that this is project-specific).
- Comparing the modified csproj file with the original, no relevant changes found.
- Delete bin folder in the project.

I can't find any files in any subdirectory of the project that could indicate designer settings.

I have the latest updated version of Blend For Visual Studio.
The project is a XAML WinRT project.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to delete the .suo file in the solution.